# How to focus a specific row in datagridview based on value in textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview `dgPersons` which content binds from database (Columns : `idPerson`, `personName`) .. in the same form I have textboxes `txtCodePerson` ,`txtPersonName`

I add data to the database by filling the textboxses and click on  `btnSave` .. then re pind the data to make the new row visible on the datagridview

Now .. I want to focus on the row which I recently add by get the value from `txtCodePerson` and set the selected row which equal that value in `idPerson` Column

Code :

```
String searchValue = txtCodePerson.Text;
dgPersons.ClearSelection();
int rowIndex = -1;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgPersons.Rows)
{
 if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
  {
    rowIndex = row.Index;
    break;
  }
}
```

But it didn't work .. after adding a row the selected row automatically go to the first row

Notice : selecting the last row will not do what I want because the datagridview data resorted alphabitcally on `personName` column after binding data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the row that its corresponding column value equals to the specified text. Then set it as current row.

For example, if you are looking for the row that its `idPerson` column equals to the text of `txtCodePerson`, then you can use following code:

```
var searchValue = txtCodePerson.Text;    
var row = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow)
    .Where(x => ((DataRowView)x.DataBoundItem)["idPerson"].ToString().Equals(searchValue))
    .FirstOrDefault();
this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0];
```

Comment: Sorry .. it didn't work ... the focus still go to the first row after binding data

Comment: The code is tested and works properly. Try to put it in the correct event handler and also use breakpoint to find the problem. When someone post an answer for you, you need to test answers in a clean environment.